# How to uninitialize a variable In Flutter / Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I define a variable `ui.Image? previewImage;` (ui refers to dart:ui).

I then start an image stream from the camera that performs YOLOX classifications and pairs them with an image, and updates the variable `previewImage` with the classification results with a function onDetected():

```
  onDetected(
    List<YoloxResults> results,
    ui.Image image,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      yoloxResults = results;
      previewImage = image;
    });
  }
```

The `yoloxResults` and `previewImage` are then displayed with a widget:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (previewImage == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        final cameraWidget = FittedBox(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: previewImage!.width.toDouble(),
            height: previewImage!.height.toDouble(),
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: YoloxResultsPainter(
                image: previewImage!,
                results: results,
                labels: labels,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

        return cameraWidget;
      },
    );
  }
```

I have a page where I switch between the above widget and another body widget via a Ternary Operator...

The first time I load the `cameraWidget`, `previewImage` is null and displays the `CircularProgressIndicator()` before the `previewImage` is set via the `onDetected()` function (which is what I want).

The second time I open the `cameraWidget` `previewImage` is already defined and an old image is displayed before the `onDetected()` function updates...  I have tried setState `previewImage = null`, which calls the `CircleProgressIndicator()` but then displays an old `previewImage` first, and before updating...

My Question: **How can I reset the previewImage variable to being uninitialized?**

**How can I remove the data assigned to previewImage?**

Comment: can you try using initState to set it null

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  Can you elaborate, maybe I'm confused... I created a function called super.initstate(); and set previewImage == null;

Comment: yes, I mean that thing, can you include full minimal widget that will reprodue the same error

Comment: previewImage == null doesn't assign null to the variable, it tests if the variable is equal to null. previewImage = null sets the variable to null.

Comment: I see.  Is there a way to un-assign it or remove its data somehow?

Comment: previewImage = null sets it to null. Do that.

Comment: I think you need to go through the Dart language tour. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: lol you are probably right

Comment: == vs =... im an idiot.  But whats interesting here is that when I set the previewImage = null; I get the progress Indicator (bc it is null), however I then get the previewImage from the last time I called the cameraWidget before it updates with a new image...

Comment: i think you should set to null when you quit the "camera" widget. How is it implemented ? a back button ? then you could catch the quit event and set to null. Btw, everything is in a statefulWidget ?

Comment: cameraWidget implementation in a stateful widget is controlled with a bool: cameraOpen... cameraOpen ? Column() : cameraWidget

Comment: Are you manually setState campaOpen = false ?

Comment: yes.  Button sets state to open camera, and a button to set state close the camera

Comment: not sure if you can access previewImage in your setState of button closing camera. Depends if you have all your code in the same statefulWidget. Can you share this part ?

Comment: So I have a Stateful Widget where previewImage is defined, and a Floating action Button , and a Body... The Floating action button has different onPressed events related to whether the camera is open... the body has a list and a cameraWidget that swap when called by the floating action button.  onPressed: () async {
  setState(() {
    cameraOpen = !cameraOpen;
  });
  await _stopImageStream();
  CustomItem customItem = await _classify();
  customList.insert(0, customItem);
  setState(() {
    previewImage = null;
  });
},